# Find string in Haystack and display that particular paragraph where the string was found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an sql resultset which is retrieved after searching through the database using the LIKE keyword. I want to display the result on a page but without showing the whole text. Just the paragraph where the result was found. Maybe even put that particular word in bold. Anyone with an idea of how best I can implement this?

Comment: might be useful http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/fastestcscaseinsstringrep.aspx

Answer (score 2):

- Get the text into a string.
- Split on your paragraph character (line break?) - `text.split('\n')`
- Iterate over each paragraph
- Get the index(es) of your keyword - `text.IndexOf("keyword")`
- Then perform some logic to cut number of characters at the start and end
- Insert bold tag with for example a string replace - `text = text.Replace("keyword", "<b>keyword</b>")`

**[Edit - added code sample]**

```
public List<string> HighLightedParagraphs(string word, string text)
{
    int charBeforeAndAfter = 100;
    List<string> matchParagraphs = new List<string>();
    Regex wordMatch = new Regex(@"\b" + word + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    foreach (string paragraph in text.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        int startIdx = -1;
        int length = -1;
        foreach (Match match in wordMatch.Matches(paragraph))
        {
            int wordIdx = match.Index;
            if (wordIdx >= startIdx && wordIdx <= startIdx + length) continue;
            startIdx = wordIdx > charBeforeAndAfter ? wordIdx - charBeforeAndAfter : 0;
            length = wordIdx + match.Length + charBeforeAndAfter < paragraph.Length
                                ? match.Length + charBeforeAndAfter
                                : paragraph.Length - startIdx;
            string extract = wordMatch.Replace(paragraph.Substring(startIdx, length), "<b>" + match.Value + "</b>");
            matchParagraphs.Add("..." + extract + "...");
        }
    }
    return matchParagraphs;
}
```

Comment: You really should have been able to do this by yourself, but I added a short sample. Used Regex instead of string.replace.

Comment: I am using the method you provided and adding it to my dataset. When I use <%#Eval("Trimmed")%> from my repeater I get System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] 

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Trimmed is what contains the return matchParagraphs;
This is what am doing. I am calling this from a function which takes the long text and creates the short one with the location of the text I was searching from. It then adds this to the dataset.

Comment: string.Join(" ", matchParagraphs)  will convert the list of strings to one string.

Comment: How do I then retrieve the strings? If I try to display them on a page all I get is System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].

I am adding the matchparams into a column on my dataset.